# Navigate on button press in React Native from the main file

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In App.js
I have

```
 const AppNavigator = DrawerNavigator ({
     [routes.Home] = {screen: HomeScreen}

   })
contentComponent:props => {
return (
 <ScrollView> 
{..props}
 <DrawerContent />
</ScrollView>
  }
 )
```

on DrawerContent I have a button that onPress I want to navigate to HomeScreen.

```
 const DrawerContent = props => 
( 
 <Button transparent onPress={props.onClickHome}>
  <Icon name="home"/> 
  </Button>
)
```

How do i bind the onClickHome to HomeScreen ? Since the button is within the Drawer that's inside the App.js , how do I access navigation ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the navigate function you wish to call as a prop to `<DrawerContent />`

Perhaps try something like the following:

```
<DrawerContent onClickHome={yourNavigateFunction} />
```

Comment: That's what I don't know how to pass.  Is there access to this.props.navigation.navigate on App.js ?

Comment: Yes, if you have access to the function within App.js, you can pass a reference to the function to content drawer from App.js

Comment: But what I'm asking is the navigate function, not how to pass properties.
How do I write a navigation function - navigatation.navigate to the screen in App.js ?

Because in other components I do it like this : 

   this.props.navigation.navigate(routes.Home)

Because I've set the screen of Home to be HomeScreen on app.js.
That's my  confusion.

Comment: Well if the navigate function already exists, which from your description seems to be the case, then it is a matter of passing props. Does the navigate function already exist in some form in one of your components? If so, you can pass if it as a prop to the content drawer and call it within that component. If you could more precisely explain where you're running into trouble and provide more of your code I might be of more help. I.E "my function is defined buy I can't seem to access it in another component... or I have access to my func as a prop but can't seem to call if with the args I want"

Comment: My App.js, which is the entry point has :
 const AppNavigator = DrawerNavigator where I have screen:HomeScreen
contentComponent:props{ where I have the ScrollView that has the DrawerContent}
And then the class App extends React.Component {
where I render the view
}
So I'm unsure where do I get the navigator here.
Cuz things gets passed down from this point, not up.

Answer (score 0):

Use next approach to be able to access to navigation from everywhere: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux